# When are Dafny sequences equal?

Tags: sequence, equality, dafny

Hi  Having defined a function that builds a sequence from a set it is easy to  verify that from equal sets the function must return equal sequences. But this is not what the results look liked

```
qr = [3, 1, 2] ==  qt = [1, 2, 3]  ??
```

I am using VScode and running what it calls Dafny 0.18.0. There is either a bug in Dafny or a misunderstanding on my part.
Any corrections welcome.

```
predicate setIsSeq<T>(t : set<T>, q : seq<T>) 
{ (|t| == |q|)  ==>
   (forall i :: (0 <= i < |q|) ==> (q[i] in t)) &&
   (forall x :: x in t ==> (x in q))
}
function method fSetToSeq<T>(t : set<T>) : (r : seq<T>)
  decreases t 
  ensures setIsSeq(t,r);
 {
  var inner := t; 
  if (|inner| == 0) then [] 
  else (
    var e :| e in inner; 
    var tx := inner - {e};
    var qx := fSetToSeq(tx);
    [e] + qx   )
  }   
  lemma {:induction s1, s2} whatIsSeq<T>(s1 : set<T>, s2 : set<T>)     
  ensures  s1 == s2 ==> fSetToSeq(s1) == fSetToSeq(s2)  {}

method Main() {
var st:set<nat> := {1,2,3};
var sr:set<nat> := {3,1,2};
assert st == sr;
var qr:seq<nat> := fSetToSeq(sr);
var qt:seq<nat> := fSetToSeq(st);
assert qr == qt;
print "qr = ", qr," ==  qt = ", qt,"  ??  \n";

var xr:seq<nat> := [1, 2, 3];
var yr:seq<nat> := [3, 1, 2];
print "yr = ", yr," !=  xr = ", xr,"  ??  \n";
assert yr != xr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, definitely a bug. This is the same bug as the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63916646/438267). `fSetToSeq` should not be allowed to be compiled. Please report on [github](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues).